# Determine if the sequence converges or diverges. If converges, find the limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Determine if the sequence converges or diverges. If converges, find the limit.

$a_n=n\sin\left({\frac 1n}\right)$

My attempt:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac1n\right)$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\times\sin\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right)$

$=\infty\times\sin0 = 0$

Solution:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}$

$f(x)=\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim\frac{-/cos(1/x)/x^2}{- 1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(1/x)=1$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)=1$

I just don't understand why the product rule give me the wrong result here. Could you explain why that happened?

Comment: $\infty \times 0$ is indeterminate. To see this, consider $\frac{1}{n} \cdot n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product rule i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right)$$

works when the limits of $a_n$ and $b_n$ exist separately. If one of the sequences is shooting off to infinity, then the limit is said to not exist for that particular sequence (check your definitions!). In cases where one limit is going to infinity and the other limit is approaching zero, you almost always want to use L'Hôpital's rule like the solution presented.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can’t apply the product rule because it requires both sequences to be convergent, which clearly isn’t the case for $a_n = n$. However, L’Hôpital’s theorem will lead to the solution. We can easily see that the theorem is indeed applicable if we rewrite the sequence, such that we get:

$\displaystyle  \lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{cos\frac{1}{n}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \cos(0) = 1$

Intuitively and less formal you can think of that result in terms of the fact that for very small angles, i.e. $x << 1$, we can use the approximation $\sin(x) \approx x$, such that for $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ we get 
 $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n} = 1$.